# Can't disable Windows Defender for some reason

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

Allright, so here's the problem, i need to disable WD because it recognises a file as a Virus, while it's not, and it's annoying BUT... I can't, it's totaly stuck, i get stuff like "My IT administrator didn't allow this" in it's own menu, and gpedit isn't installed on a HOME version of windows ... So i've been looking for some workaround, and so far it didn't work as well.

Some guy said "Policy Plus" could help me out on it, but in the end, it doesn't work, because he doesn't find a windows file.

And a thing called "Gpedit enabler" didn't work either, because the .bat file failed to get access to what it needed ...

To make it clear, this is my laptop, i've never had any issue before this, and i'm totaly confused ...

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend disabling Windows Defender because of one single file.
It is after all the anti-virus which is the best-integrated into Windows.

A simple solution would be to exclude that single file, or even its entire folder,
from Windows Defender scanning.

Exclusions are created this way :

- Go to *Start > Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Security > Virus & thread protection*.
- Click *Virus & threat protection settings* on the new screen
- Under Exclusions, click *Add or remove exclusions*
- Click the `+` button
- Choose File Or Folder
- Browse to the file or folder and select it.

Selecting folders will also apply to their sub-folders.

[image]